# Is there a way to automatically indent nested sections in css?

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<section>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
  <section>
    <h1>Test2</h1>
    <p>Text2</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

And I would like it to appear similarly indented:

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Text</p>
<h2 style="margin-left: 40px">Test2</h2>
<p style="margin-left: 40px">Text2</p>
```

Comment: can you tell exactly what do you want?

Comment: @Roberrrt Sure, but that is not the OP's question.

Comment: I don't find the question vague at all. Just not very well researched, that's all.

Comment: i like it, see how everything but the 1st `<section>` tag is nested, so he would like to know can css target the nested `<section>` tags, which is `section`s, `h1`, `p`... relevant to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this, if you don't want to add any classes:

```css
section > section {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
  <section>
    <h1>Test2</h1>
    <p>Text2</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

This will add a left margin of 40px to every section that is a direct child of a section.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `margin-left` on `section` element but not on the first one.

```css
section:not(.first) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="first">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
  <section>
    <h1>Test2</h1>
    <p>Text2</p>
    <section>
      <h1>Test3</h1>
      <p>Text3</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <section>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <p>Text</p>
     <section style="margin-left:40px">
      <h1>Test2</h1>
      <p>Text2</p>
     </section>
   </section>
```